# Unity 2D switch direction in an auto runner

Tags: unity, 2d

I'm new to Unity and I'm trying to make a 2d endless runner (something like Super Meat Boy Forever), and one idea was that when the player touches a wall he would change direction.

I tried to implement the mechanic, but in game is very strange and buggy. My idea was to change the speed value from positive to negative and vice versa when the character collides to a wall (I used a layer mask for that). If someone could help me I would be very grateful.
Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed;
public float jumpForce;
private Rigidbody2D rb; 
public bool grounded; 
public bool walled;
public LayerMask whatIsGround;
public LayerMask whatIsWall;
private Collider2D myCollider;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start() {
    rb=GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();   
    myCollider=GetComponent<Collider2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update() { 
    grounded = Physics2D.IsTouchingLayers(myCollider, whatIsGround);
    walled = Physics2D.IsTouchingLayers(myCollider, whatIsWall);
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, rb.velocity.y);
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {  
        if (grounded) {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        }
    }
   
    if (walled) {   
       speed = -speed;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Did your code format the way you wanted? If not, consult the [help] for formatting guidance, and edit your question so that your code is clearly legible. You should also be sure to include a clear description or example diagrams/screengrabs/videos of the bug(s) you need help fixing.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what kind of bugs you are seeing with your code. If I had to guess, I think Physics2D.IsTouchingLayers is probably returning true every frame after you hit a wall since it does not move far enough after you change directions. You might want to try raycasting in the direction you are running in instead.